# SSMS 2017 FOR JSON truncation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, sql-server-data-tools

I'm attempting to return a sql query in json format using

```
FOR JSON AUTO
```

everything works fine until i attempt to return the full result set.
The output is being either truncated and or appended CR/LF every 2034 characters.

I've tried some of the workarounds, output to file, change the output limitations etc... with no success.

In SSIS when assigning the result set to a variable of type Object. I don't know how to get the string stored. I get this is an object but it's just a giant string that can be interpreted as an object. How can I return the string literal of the 'object'?